# What is the size in bytes of the entire nixos cache at https://cache.nixos.org?

Tags: caching, nixos

Just out of curiosity. How much bytes have accumulated there?

I regularly download Gigabytes from there when I do garbage collection and enter the nix-shell of my haskell project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NixOS foundation says cache.nixos.org has more than 120TB. You can find this number at the end of [this](https://nixos.org/community/index.html) page.